# PHP7 SoapClient Issues

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client, php-7

I have recently upgraded from PHP5.4 to PHP7.  Boy was that a change, but that is beside the point.

I'm having issues with a SoapService since the upgrade.

Here is what my SoapRequest looked like on PHP5.4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:usaepay" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<env:Body>
    <ns1:searchTransactions env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <Token xsi:type="ns1:ueSecurityToken">
        <ClientIP xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</ClientIP>
        <PinHash xsi:type="ns1:ueHash">
            <HashValue xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</HashValue>
            <Seed xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</Seed>
            <Type xsi:type="xsd:string">sha1</Type>
        </PinHash>
        <SourceKey xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</SourceKey>
    </Token>
    <Search enc:itemType="ns1:SearchParam" enc:arraySize="3" xsi:type="ns1:SearchParamArray">
        <item xsi:type="ns1:SearchParam">
            <Field xsi:type="xsd:string">created</Field>
            <Type xsi:type="xsd:string">gt</Type>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-07-26</Value>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns1:SearchParam">
            <Field xsi:type="xsd:string">created</Field>
            <Type xsi:type="xsd:string">lt</Type>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-07-27</Value>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns1:SearchParam">
            <Field xsi:type="xsd:string">response</Field>
            <Type xsi:type="xsd:string">eq</Type>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">A</Value>
        </item>
    </Search>
    <MatchAll xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</MatchAll>
    <Start xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</Start>
    <Limit xsi:type="xsd:integer">9999</Limit>
    <Sort xsi:type="xsd:string">TransID</Sort>
</ns1:searchTransactions>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here is what the request looks like running the exact same piece of code on PHP7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:usaepay" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
<env:Body>
    <ns1:searchTransactions env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
    <Token xsi:type="ns1:ueSecurityToken">
        <ClientIP xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</ClientIP>
        <PinHash xsi:type="ns1:ueHash">
            <HashValue xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</HashValue>
            <Seed xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</Seed>
            <Type xsi:type="xsd:string">sha1</Type>
        </PinHash>
        <SourceKey xsi:type="xsd:string">*redacted*</SourceKey>
    </Token>
    <Search enc:itemType="ns2:Map" enc:arraySize="3" xsi:type="ns1:SearchParamArray">
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Field</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">created</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Type</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">gt</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Value</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-07-26</value>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Field</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">created</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Type</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">lt</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Value</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2016-07-26</value>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Field</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">response</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Type</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">eq</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <key xsi:type="xsd:string">Value</key>
                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">A</value>
            </item>
        </item>
    </Search>
    <MatchAll xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</MatchAll>
    <Start xsi:type="xsd:integer">0</Start>
    <Limit xsi:type="xsd:integer">9999</Limit>
    <Sort xsi:type="xsd:string">created</Sort>
</ns1:searchTransactions>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here is the relevant PHP code:  (Note $sec) is the security information that has been redacted.

```
$param = array(
            array('Field' => 'created', 'Type' => 'gt', 'Value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-07-26'))), 
            array('Field' => 'created', 'Type' => 'lt', 'Value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-07-26'))),
            array('Field' => 'response', 'Type' => 'eq', 'Value' => 'A')
            );

$matchAll = true;
$start = 0;
$limit = 9999;
$sort = 'TransID';

$this->advClient = new SoapClient($this->adv_wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$result = $this->advClient->searchTransactions($sec, $searchParam, $matchAll, $start, $limit, $sort);
```

What I end up with is an error.  I think the issue is that in PHP7 it is wrapping and adding extra "item" tags.  However some of the functions still work no problem.  Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, I used wsdltophp.com and created a class for the WSDL and everything worked fine.